# XCUITest, UIDatePicker, adjustToPickerWheelValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, xcuitest

I'm writing an XCUITest. I have a view with a UIDatePicker on it (NOT a regular picker).
I'm trying to set the date using adjustToPickerWheelValue.
This crashes with the following error:

caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[XCUIElement(XCUIElementTypePickerWheel) adjustToPickerWheelValue:]_block_invoke can only be called with elements of type XCUIElementTypePickerWheel, not valid for DatePicker."

This implies of course that this method is not available for the UIDatePicker. 
I've gone through the apple site and it states pretty clearly that it IS supported.

I can't find any examples of this used for a date picker.

It's possible of course that I'm just not setting it right (I'm not sure how one would pass a string date, for example).

This is the code I'm trying:

```
XCUIElement *DOB;

XCUIElementQuery *DOBList = app.datePickers;
DOB = [DOBList elementBoundByIndex:0];
NSLog(@"DOB = %@\n", [DOB description]);
[DOB adjustToPickerWheelValue:@"SOME DATE GOES HERE?"];
```

BTW - description is of a DatePicker.
Printing [DOB value] just returns an empty string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For using UIDatePickers, I do like that:

```
XCUIApplication().datePickers.firstMatch.pickerWheels["CurrentValue"].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "NewValue")
```

You have to do that for each picker of the UIDatePicker.

Comment: That actually works! Translated for Objective-C:      [app.datePickers.firstMatch.pickerWheels[@"2019"] adjustToPickerWheelValue: @"1995"];
It's a bit fragile because you have to know the date it's at to change values.
    [app.datePickers.firstMatch.pickerWheels[@"2019"] adjustToPickerWheelValue: @"1995"];
    [app.datePickers.firstMatch.pickerWheels[@"October"] adjustToPickerWheelValue: @"December"];
    [app.datePickers.firstMatch.pickerWheels[@"10"] adjustToPickerWheelValue: @"31"];